# How do you sort an array by only using specific elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm using an array as a temporary inventory (as part of a game). There are *items* and *values*, each being a **string**. They are always followed.

The value or quantity determines how much of that item you have.

For example: `inventoryArray = ['bananas', '5', 'berries', '8', 'apples','3']`

In the example above you would have a **banana** with a quantity of **5**

My goal is to **sort the array by quantity**. So a function could return `['berries', '8','bananas', '5' 'apples','3']`

Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely consider an data structure with a key/value pair instead of an array. A simple object would do your manipulation well.  inventoryArray = { banana : 5, berries: 8, apples: 3 }

Comment: Use an array of objects: `inventoryArray = [{ name: "bananas", count: 5 }, { ... }]` Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0rjfhnv2/

Comment: An object based inventory will do the trick. Thank you for your quick responses!

Comment: @ChrisG Your answer works flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this seems like A Bad Idea™ and you really should consider using a more suitable data structure.

Having said that, there are ways to do it.

In the snippet below I first convert the array to an object via [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so you end up with a structure like this (which you should consider using in the first place):

```js
{
  bananas: 5,
  berries: 8,
  apples: 3
}
```

I then sort that object's [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), producing a sorted array of pairs:

```js
[
  ['apples', 3],
  ['bananas', 5],
  ['berries', 8],
]
```

Finally, [flattening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) that array produces the result you're after:

```js
['apples', 3, 'bananas', 5, 'berries', 8]
```

Again, I agree with the comments above suggesting that this calls for a more suitable data structure, but if you *have* to do it this way for some reason you could.

```js
const inventoryArray = ['bananas', '5', 'berries', '8', 'apples','3']

const quantities = inventoryArray.reduce((acc, item, index, arr) => {
  // skip odd indices (the quantities)
  if (index % 2 === 1) {
    return acc;
  }
  
  // add the product and qty (index + 1) to the result
  return {
    ...acc,
    [item]: Number(arr[index + 1])
  }
}, {});

// sort the key value pairs
const arr = Object.entries(quantities).sort(([, qtyA], [, qtyB]) => qtyA - qtyB);

console.log(arr.flat());
```